# setTimeout and node.js polling

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I need to poll for completion of an analysis (that I'm farming out to another server). I'm using setTimout to check every N minutes to see if a response is true, and if so, to send an email etc. The problem is that setTimout doesn't work all the time and somehow this process is failing to continue to poll for the status of the analysis. (sometimes it works fine)

Can someone explain why setTimout gets "lost" sometimes and the scalable solution to poll for the success of results that may take a while? (a few hours).

```
var that = this;
exports.doThis = function(myParms, checkEveryNMinutes) {

  myLib.getStatus(myParms, function(theStatus) {

        if(theStatus.isDone){

            //do stuff

        }else{

            setTimeout(function(){that.doThis(myParms,
                                              checkEveryNMinutes)
                                  }, checkEveryNMinutes);

        } 

    }, function(err) { console.log(err); }

  );

}
```

Comment: The `setTimeout` is only called in the success callback, if the `getStatus()` fails, the timeout won't be set again. You should set your timeout at the end of the `doThis()` function

Comment: hi sorry i simplified it for the post example, i check the status for error and execute another condition, so you can assume that i always get a response of yes or no

Comment: hi Mateon1 maybe you are right but instead i added it to the error method in getStatus and it seems to be working... so maybe their is network problem or something and the timer gets lost when there is an error in the getStatus... testng now